# Interesting Pattern - Adding or Multiplying Sequential Integers and Then Reducing

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, arithmetic, pattern-recognition

I noticed that if you sequentially add integers together, or even multiply them, and then reduce the result, an interesting pattern emerges.

```
(+1) 1  >> 1
(+2) 3  >> 3
(+3) 6  >> 6
(+4) 10 >> 1
(+5) 15 >> 6
(+6) 21 >> 3
(+7) 28 >> 1
(+8) 36 >> 9
(+9) 45 >> 9
```

This pattern, `1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 3, 1, 9, 9`, repeats itself without end. Obviously this is due at least in part to the fact that we use a base 10 number system.

1. Are there any other interesting patterns that I'm missing?
2. Is there a logical reason for this?

If you double the numbers, `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc`, and then reduce them, you get a different pattern, `1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 5` that repeats itself endlessly.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce the result?"

Comment: @EeveeTrainer i mean like `10 = 1 + 0 = 1` or `561 = 5 + 6 + 1 = 12 = 1 + 2 = 3`

Comment: Ah, so taking the sum of the numbers' digits repeatedly until you get a one-digit number, I see. Might be appropriate to explain that more explicitly in the OP (unless it's actually a commonly-used term, still a novice with this but I've never heard of that).

Comment: The repetition, and basic patterns, have to do with the "reduced" value having the same remainder as the original value when it's divided by $9$, and the sum of the integers from $1$ to $n$, inclusive, being $\frac{\left(n\right)\left(n + 1\right)}{2}$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer i believe that is the term. it's the only term i've heard when people describe this. there could be more terms, but i've never heard of them

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for your input! i'm not exactly sure i understand your response, specifically `reduced value having the same remainder as the original value when it's divided by 9`? this is how i'm understanding your response: let's use `1+2+3+4+5=15=6` for example; you're saying that `15` and `6` have the same remainder which is ??? when `6/9`?

Comment: @Anthony I meant as you said, i.e., in your case that $12345$, $15$ and $6$ all have the same remainder of $6$ when divided by $9$.  However, note the answer is not quite that simple, due to $0$ and $9$ both having remainder of $0$, but this is an important aspect of what you are observing.

Comment: @JohnOmielan i'm confused? how do you get a remainder of 6 when dividing `15` and `6` by `9`? or are you simply saying that `15` and `6` are both remainders (of `6`) themselves? but if that's the case, what do you mean by `when divided by 9`?

Comment: What I mean when I say "divided by 9" is that it will give you an integer multiplier and a remainder between $0$ and $8$, inclusive.

Comment: "*9 can be divided by each of those numbers, 1, 3, 6, 9, into an integer*," nine cannot be divided by six into an integer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan ohhhhhhhh right right. yeah thats a mistake on my part. ill change that. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to all of these question lies in what actually happens when you "reduce" a number by repeatedly summing its digits. In particular, the following is true

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $n$ is divisible by $9$, its reduction will be $9$. Otherwise, its reduction will be the remainder of $n$ when divided by $9$.

Here, for formal purposes, "remainder" means the number $0\leq r<9$ such that you can write
$$n=9q+r$$
For instance, the remainder of $23$ divided by $9$ is $5$ since $9\times 2 + 5 = 23$. Note that $2+3=5$ as well.

The basic thing to notice in order to prove this is that the difference between an integer $n$ and the sum of its digits $s$ is always a multiple of $9$. For instance, $23-(2+3)=18=9\times 2$. You can prove this by looking at the expanded form of decimal representation; in particular if $n$ has decimal expansion $d_kd_{k-1}\ldots d_1d_0$ for some sequence of digits $d_i$, we have
$$n=10^kd_k+10^{k-1}d_{k-1}+\ldots+10^1\cdot d_1 + 10^0\cdot d_0.$$
Then, the sum of the digits is
$$s=d_k+d_{k-1}+\ldots+d_1+d_0.$$
The difference between these two values is
$$n-s=(10^k-1)d_k+(10^{k-1}-1)d_{k-1}+\ldots+(10^1-1)\cdot d_1 + (10^0-1)\cdot d_0.$$
However, note that $$10^k-1=\underbrace{99\ldots 99}_{k\text{ digits}}=9\cdot \underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{k\text{ digits}}.$$
Thus, every term in the difference $n-s$ is $9$ times something, so the whole thing is $9$ times something - so $n-s$ is divisible by $9$.

You can repeat this logic as many times as necessary to see that if $r$ was the reduction of $n$, then $n-r$ is divisible by $9$ - but then you find that there are only actually $9$ positive single digits numbers - and $r$ is definitely one of them - so it's only a matter of checking that there is only one positive single digit number $r$ so that $n-r$ is a multiple of $9$.

---

Okay, so why does this help us? Well, it reveals another surprising fact:

> Let $n$ and $n'$ be positive integers with reductions $r$ and $r'$ respectively. The reduction of $n+n'$ and $n\cdot n'$ equal the reductions of $r+r'$ or $r\cdot r'$ respectively.

If you want to prove this, you basically write $n=9q+r$ and $n'=9q+r'$ and then note that $n+n'=9(q+q')+(r+r')$ then $nn'=9(9qq'+qr'+q'r)+rr'$ and use the last theorem, which gets rid of all those multiples of $9$ being added, since they can't change the result.

The significance is that you get a multiplication table and addition table where, given the two reductions, you can look up the reduction of the sum and product without knowing the original two numbers. Those tables look like this:

[image: Addition Table]

[image: Multiplication Table]

This framework basically sets up the answer to your questions: the reductions of the doubling sequence is easiest to explain. To find that sequence, you start at $1$, then, using the table above, multiply that by $2$. You repeat that for a while - and eventually you get back to $1$. The sequence is bound to repeat from there, since you've entered a loop. Note that this method completely forgets about what the number your reducing was - it just cares about the reduction!

For the addition, note that as we add the integers together sequentially, we'll be adding reductions where we start at $1$, add $2$, and so on - until we add $9$. Then instead of adding $10$, we add its reduction of $1$, then instead of $11$ we add $2$ - and so on. So, we are adding an infinitely cycling sequence of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ instead of thinking about adding the integers up sequentially. However, we note that after we add $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9$, we get $9$ - which has a special property; in the above table, we always have $9+r=r$. Thus, when we jump back to adding a reduction of $1$, we get back to a sum with reduction $1$ - and the cycle repeats.

In more generality, this sort of reasoning is known as modular arithmetic. There's a lot of interesting things that happen when one develops this theory further.

Comment: A very detailed & well done explanation.  There is just one small thing I saw to correct.  About a fifth of the way down, you have an equation starting with "$10^k = 99\ldots 99$" with "$k$ digits" below it.  You should have a "$- 1$" after $10^k$.

Comment: ill will be reading this as soon as i get a moment. thanks for your response my friend!

Comment: "Let n be a positive integer. If n is divisible by 9, its reduction will be 9. Otherwise, its reduction will be the remainder of n when divided by 9." I think this is what the other buddy was trying to say, but I understand it the way you put it. Though why would it be the remainder after dividing by 9? Also, why are all of the resulting totals of adding the sequential integers together divisible by 3?

Comment: that is absolutely fascinating. `92 = 9 * 10 + 2` (`9 + 2 = 11 = 1 + 1 = 2`) or `165 = 18 * 9 + 3`!!

Comment: is all of this due to the fact that it's a base 10 number system? would one find similar patterns in different number systems?

Comment: @Anthony For the first comment: It's the remainder since, whenever you sum the digits of a number, you subtract a multiple of $9$ from it (e.g. $92$ becomes $11$ by subtracting $81=9\times 9$). Repeating this, you get that to get from $n$ to $r$, you subtract some multiple of $9$, so $n-9q=r$ for some $q$. Then, rearranging gives $n=9q+r$. Since we know $r$ is a single digit number, this turns out to be the remainder (and this is the only possibility since if we successively subtract $9$ from a number, we'll only once end up between $1$ and $9$). Basically, it's the only possibility.

Comment: ...Not all the resulting totals are divisible by $3$ - for instance, $1$ and $1+2+3+4=10$ are not. In general, every third total will not be. There's a formula for the sum of $1+2+\ldots+n=\frac{n\cdot (n+1)}2$. From this, you can see that $3$ divides the sum whenever $3$ divides $n$ or $n+1$ - which happens $2/3$ of the time. (It's also worth noting that almost everything in this post works by replacing "reduction" with "remainder when divided by $k$" for any $k$ - so if you work things out with $k=3$, you can get an addition table for those remainders and see it there)

Comment: ...Nothing in this post is specific to base $10$ - essentially, everything works if you replace $9$ by $10-1$ in whatever base you're in (or, otherwise said, $b-1$ in base $b$). You'll get a (eventually) repeating pattern of reductions in any base, though the length of the pattern might change. It's worth looking at.

Comment: @MiloBrandt very interesting. thanks for all of your input. so this is called modular arithmetic?

Comment: @Anthony Yes - modular arithmetic, more generally, deals with remainders (so, this whole post talks about "mod $9$" structure)

Comment: @MiloBrandt thanks again my friend!!